# Как написать генератор, который принимает список списков, и возвращает их плоское представление?

Tags: python, list

Написать генератор, который принимает список списков, и возвращает их плоское представление. Например:

```
nested_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    [1, 2, None],
]
for item in  flat_generator(nested_list):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для двумерного списка это просто:

```
nested_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    [1, 2, None],
]

def flat_generator(a: list) -> list:
    return [x for sublist in a for x in sublist]

for item in  flat_generator(nested_list):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

А что вы подразумеваете под генератором? Вот такое выражение по сути тоже генератор:

```
nested_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    [1, 2, None]]

gen = (i for l in nested_list for i in l)
gen
'''
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000220017EA7B0>
'''
next(gen)
'''
'a'
'''
type(gen)
'''
generator
```

**UPD**

кстати такая функция тоже генератор:

```
def gen(nl):
    for l in nl: 
        for i in l:
            yield i

g = gen(nested_list)
g
'''
<generator object gen at 0x0000022001819740>
'''
next(g)
'''
'a'
'''
for i in g: print(i)
'''
a
b
c
d
e
f
1
2
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так что-ли? *Решение в лоб:*

```
nested_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    [1, 2, None],
]
for i in nested_list[:]:
    for x in i: nested_list.append(x)
    nested_list.remove(i)
print(nested_list)
```

**Вывод:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 1, 2, None]
```

Comment: Почти..... Надо что бы вывод был организован сверху вниз и  через for item in  flat_generator(nested_list):
    print(item)

Comment: Что значит "Сверху вниз"?

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) решает вашу задачу:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(nested_list):
    print(i)
```

Если вы не хотите пользоваться библиотекой, то подойдёт вложенный генератор:

```
for i in (i for lst in nested_list for i in lst):
    print(i)
```

Если вложенный генератор кажется слишком сложным, тогда вложенные циклы:

```
for lst in nested_list:
    for i in lst:
        print(i)
```